# Is it ok to change the access modifiers by creating a new header file?

Tags: c++, access-modifiers

Recently I just wanted to change the access property of class in webkit.framework to get access to a private data member.

My method is to use a new header file to change the member access control property. Is this ok?

I am not very sure about this. So I just want to know how C++ implements the access control (public, private, protected), and in which phase (compiling or runtime).

Comment: Just to be sure I understood correctly: you copied the existing class declaration from that project's source header file, changed some member variable from private to public, and are using the modified header? Are you linking with libraries that were compiled with the original header?

Comment: Please provide more context. Why would you want to change the access modifiers? Is this really a good idea - or was declaring that member as private such a bad idea in the first place? How does your code look like? You know how `public`, `private`, and `protected` works in C++, don't you?

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi, I know how to use it. Because ios doesn't supply some api to access Worker object in webkit, but need to get it, so I just want to get it from other object, and unfortunately. There's no public method to get it, so I have to get it as a data member.

Comment: @ Mat, yes, I use the original header. But need the internal object and whose header need not to be exposed to me.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is OK to modify the access specifiers such as public, private, protected which are defined in a probably third-party header file.

C++ enforces this kind of access specifiers ONLY during compilation. There is no mechanism in C++ to enforce access specifiers during Run-time.

But one would better NOT to change access specifier from private to protected/public because there won't be any guaranty that it holds a desired value, any point of time during execution.

Comment: by the way, where can I find the specific introduction of c++ access control mechanism?

Comment: @Chogri Bjarn stroustrup, in his book named The Design and Evolution of C++ says - "The C++ access control mechanisms provide protection against accident - not against fraud."

He continues to say that "Any programming language that supports access to raw memory will leave data open to deliberate tampering in ways that violate the explicitly type rules specified for a given data item."

You can refer this book for more details.